# Job applications: how important is it for letters of recommendation to be on letterhead?

Tags: career

Hello,

The context for this question: for liberal arts colleges, one of my letter writers is a fifth-grade teacher that I spent a year teaching with.  She has written her letter, but is having difficulty obtaining approval for using letterhead.  Nothing substantive, its a pure logistical issue.

Some deadlines are coming up.  Will it negatively impact my application if her letter is not on school letterhead?

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm sure the answer depends on who is reading it, but I would be very surprised if it turned out to be a problem. 

Comment: Agree with Thierry. 

Comment: Given that I've seen a number of letters of recommendation submitted in mathjobs as plain text, I don't really see the issue.

That said, for the love of pete, don't submit letters to mathjobs as plain text; at least take the 3 seconds to put it in the generic latex letter environment.

Comment: Agree with everyone else. I have seen recommendation letters written in all sorts of formats.